# How to run unity code in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

[image: Attached initial screen of my IDE]

[image: navigation and projects browse]I Have an existing unity code, I need to fix some issues in this code but I have don't sufficient knowledge in unity. I have downloaded and setup unity environment on my Macbook. Please suggest me how I can run my existing project here.

Thank in Advance.

Comment: you have a unity 3d IDE

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P yes I have unity 3d IDE.
Thank for your reply.

Comment: Do you know about deploy screen. can you capture and share it

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P  Please check my edited question with screen shoots.

Comment: Why do you assume Xcode is involved in this?

Comment: iOS of course doesn't run Java since iOS requires all code to be compiled AOT to xcode / objective c. When you build an iOS project, Unity just creates an xcode project which then can be built using xcode. You are free to change the code that Unity has cross compiled, however you have to do this every time when you rebuild the xcode project from Unity.

Comment: You can simulate Xcode in unity using xcode simulator, 
In Unity, you must click on Build Settings > Player Settings And in Inspector, choose settings for iOS > Other Settings > SDK Version and make sure "Simulator SDK" is selected.

Now in Xcode, it can be viewed in the iPhone Simulator.

Comment: @Droppy  I am new in Unity so I was believe xcode can also run this code using unity IDE. Thanks

Comment: Looking at your question the code you need to fix is C# which will be done using MonoDevelop (default) or VS Code.  Under Windows you can use Visual Studio.  Xcode won't be involved until deployment time and you won't be editting code at that stage, unless you have specialized native-integration in your project (fairly unlikely).